# Magento 1.9 running slow on frontend on localhost and production servers

Tags: magento-1.9, database, performance, ubuntu, mamp

I'm trying to speed up Magento 1.9.0.1.  It's taking something like a minute or so on localhost MAMP 5, and page speeds on production are loading over 10 seconds. I've tried full page cache extensions, removing overridden templates, disabling all third party extensions, and truncating large database tables. The site ran moderately fast for about 5 years. The first sign of problems was on the production server when the cart page started taking over 10 seconds to load.

[image: Magento profiler output]

Comment: Found out it may be related to the core_url_rewrite table being so large.

Comment: Have you resolved your delay?  If so, please tell us how you corrected the delay.

Comment: We had to give the site it's own Virtual Machine.  And truncate the core_url_rewrite table.  Other than that it's still having some speed issues.

Comment: For speed issues, Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.